# Why would one use IEnumerable<T> in an interface definition if the class implementing the interface will be using List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ienumerable

I am currently working through a .NET Web API tutorial located [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations).  In the example, we have an interface defined in a model class like so:

```
namespace ProductStore.Models
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> GetAll();
        Product Get(int id);
        Product Add(Product item);
        void Remove(int id);
        bool Update(Product item);
    }
}
```

Then, later in the tutorial, we implement this interface like so:

```
namespace ProductStore.Models
{
    public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        private List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        private int _nextId = 1;

        public ProductRepository()
        {
            Add(new Product { Name = "Tomato soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1.39M });
            Add(new Product { Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M });
            Add(new Product { Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M });
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public Product Get(int id)
        {
            return products.Find(p => p.Id == id);
        }

        public Product Add(Product item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }
            item.Id = _nextId++;
            products.Add(item);
            return item;
        }

        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            products.RemoveAll(p => p.Id == id);
        }

        public bool Update(Product item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }
            int index = products.FindIndex(p => p.Id == item.Id);
            if (index == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            products.RemoveAt(index);
            products.Add(item);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, why is the interface written so that `GetAll()` returns `IEnumerable<Product>` if the implementation is going to be specifically operating on a `List<Product>`?

I am assuming this is to facilitate reuse so that some other `IProductRepository` implementation could use a different `IEnumerable<Product>` (though an example of this would be nice, because I can't think of one, not that I doubt it exists, I'm just not ultra experienced).

Assuming reuse is the goal indeed, then why is the implementation written like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
{
    return products;
}
```

Instead of like this:

```
public List<Product> GetAll()
{
    return products;
}
```

Does the framework or compiler not have the ability to see that `public List<Product> GetAll()` is derivable from `public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()`?

Comment: Because that means you can change it to something other than `List<T>` in the future without breaking the interface contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two main reasons:

- this hides the actual implementation so that the consumer doesn't do anything they shouldn't with the data (e.g. add or remove items directly from the list). Obviously, the consumer can cast the result to `List<T>`, but they would be relying on an undocumented implementation detail, so if you change it later and it breaks their code, it will be their fault.
- if someday you need to change the implementation to use something other than a `List<T>`, you can do it without any visible change for the consumer.

Answer (score 2):

You want changes to your `List<T>` to operate through your repository methods and not give the user direct access to the `List<T>` - thus, you return an `IEnumerable<T>` so that they cannot change the underlying collection

Comment: Is it not true that the user can still cast the value to a List<T>?

Comment: Also note, there is a code analysis rule that advises against it: [Do not expose generic lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28DONOTEXPOSEGENERICLISTS%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV3.5%22%29&rd=true)

Comment: stuartd, list.AsReadOnly() will prevent the cast hack

Comment: sure, they could cast the returned `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>`, and in this case it would work (do they know it's a `List<T>` without reflection?).  The user can do any number of things to sabotage themselves, the idea is to make it make it difficult for them to do so and ultimately their responsibility when they have problems.

Comment: @stuard: an interface defines a contract, if you respect it you're sure it works. If not, you're assuming the risks of potential problems. Casting IEnumerable to a more specialized type breaks the contract ...

Comment: @p.s.w.g - Thanks for that link.  It was very helpful.  This in turn beckons me to ask how you found that.  I find some of MSDN to be very difficult to navigate.  I follow the documentation of the .NET framework thanks to their hierarchical links tracing back to classes that the class at hand inherits from or implements.  However, I see no such breadcrumb on the page you linked.  How does one navigate to find other code analysis rules?

Comment: @stuartd - Great suggestion on `list.AsReadOnly()`.  Can it be assumed that if the only consumers will be other bits of code written by me, then malice is not an issue?  Can it even **be** assumed (or ensured by design) that nothing but my own code will consume this?

Comment: @bubbleking I think I got there directly from Google. This version would probably be more helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142(v=vs.120).aspx